# Do all events end

Tags: time, events

[This thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15464/do-durations-really-end) included a request: "can you give an example of an event that doesn't end".

Must all events end?

Comment: Is the real number line an event?

Comment: I would say no, making my initial comment irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physically, perhaps the universe will come to a standstill, and from then on there won't be any more events.

But I don't see any *logical* reason, something in the event concept itself, why an event can't go on forever. For example, consider a small round patch, whose colors change constantly. Or a particle that moves through space, and will never stop. Or a perpetuum mobile..

Comment: ok good answer, thanks. if an event doesn't end, can its end get closer?

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN You're welcome. If an event doesn't end, then there is no "its end". So "its end" cannot get closer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this depends a great deal on how you define an *event*.

Intuitively, I want to define the term "event" to refer to a particular moment when an actor acts upon an object, in which case each event is quite short and yes, all events end almost as soon as they begin.

I could also see a definition of "event" that encompasses a large number of actions, possibly even smaller events, such as considering a war a single event comprised of a number of battles, each of which is itself an event, and each of which is in turn comprised of smaller events (sword swings, trigger pulls, chemical interactions, ...).

So the answer to this question seems to be quite context sensitive.

Comment: ok... hmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN Can you please define "event?"

Comment: oh i don't mean anything technical just a changing state of affairs

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN If you are responding to me, including '@user4894' will alert me to your response. If an event is a "changing state of affairs," then if a particle moves according to the law f(x) = x^2 for all real numbers x, is that not a series of events with no beginning and no end?